# Upper and Lower Limits of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

***If we partition a sequence into a finite number of subsequences then the upper and lower limit of the sequence are equal to the maximum upper limit and minimum lower limit of the subsequences.***

Has anybody some proof of it, or at least some hint? Or maybe some book that does this proof...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:

This deals with the $\sup$, the $\inf$ is the same.

The basic idea is that if you have a set $S$ and a partition $P_k$ of $S$ (that is, $S = P_1 \cup \cdots p_n$, the $P_k$ are non-empty and pairwise disjoint), then
you have $\sup S = \max_k \sup P_k$.

In the case of the subsequences, each $P_k$ is infinite (corresponding to each subsequence), and the set $S$ is of the form $S = \{n,n+1,... \}$.